# Transform and Pivot in Excel - MS Query

Tags: excel-2007, transform, ms-query

I have 4 field in my table :

```html
NO. | Specification | Specification Value | Description

1      Color               Blue             a
1      Size                 6"              a
2      Color               Red              b
2      Size                 8"              b
```

I am trying to Pivot it and its giving me an error.

```html
TRANSFORM FIRST(Specification Value)
SELECT items.'No.'
FROM items
GROUP BY items.'No.'
PIVOT Specification
```

The error is : "Syntax error(missing operator) in query expression 'FIRST(Specification Value)'."

Please help. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the space in the `Specification Value`. The First() function takes one expression or argument. You are passing it two, so it thinks you are passing an expression with two arguments and have forgotten the operator.

Comment: Thank you Teylyn, the space was not the problem. I was missing an operator -> first(`Specification Value`)